# Recorrer una ventana modal por registro

Tags: php, bootstrap, modal, foreach

**Edit:** Actualicé el código con la ayuda que me brindaron pero tampoco funciona, anexo lo último que intenté (*porque intente de varias manera más pero niguna me funcionó*)

No sé como hacer para rellenar una ventana modal con datos traidos desde la base de datos, pude recorrer cada registro y mostrarlo pero a la hora de abrir la ventana modal siempre me la rellena con los datos del primer registro, tengo lo siguiente:

```
<?php
    $contador = 0;
    ?>

    <?php
        foreach ($trabajos as $trabajo) {
        $contador = $contador+1
    ?>
    <div class="card mb-5 shadow">
        <div>
            <h5 class="card-header border-danger border-opacity-25"><b><?php echo $trabajo->titulo;?></span></b></h5>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <ul class="list-unstyled pb-2">
                <li><h6 class="card-title color-azul"><b><i class="fa-solid fa-list pe-1"></i>Tema:</b><span class="ps-1 text-dark fw-light"><?php echo $trabajo->tema;?></span></h6></li>
                <li><h6 class="card-title color-azul"><b><i class="fa-solid fa-users pe-1"></i>Alumnos:</b><span class="ps-1 text-dark fw-light"><?php echo $trabajo->autor1. ', ' .$trabajo->autor2. ', ' .$trabajo->autor3. ', ' .$trabajo->autor4. ', ' .$trabajo->autor5?></span></h6></li>
                <li><h6 class="card-title color-azul"><b><i class="fa-solid fa-calendar-check pe-1"></i>Fecha de Aprobación:</b><span class="ps-1 text-dark fw-light"><?php echo $trabajo->fechadeaprobacion;?></span></h6></li>
                <li><h6 class="card-title color-azul"><b><i class="fa-solid fa-upload pe-1"></i>Fecha de Carga:</b><span class="ps-1 text-dark fw-light"><?php echo $trabajo->fechadecarga;?></span></h6></li>
            </ul>
            <hr>
            <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
                <!-- TRIGGER DE VENTANA MODAL -->
                <button class="btn btn-danger border border-1 rounded w-25" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#staticBackdrop_<?php echo $contador ?>"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-info pe-1"></i>Ver más...</button>
                <div class="col-2 d-flex justify-content-end align-items-center">
                    <a href="editar.php?ID=<?php echo $trabajo->ID;?>"><button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-warning me-1"><i class="fa-solid fa-square-pen pe-1"></i>Editar</button></a>
                    <a onclick="return confirm('¿Estás seguro de eliminar este registro?');" href="eliminar.php?ID=<?php echo $trabajo->ID;?>"><button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger"><i class="fa-solid fa-trash-can pe-1"></i>Eliminar</button></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Modal:

```
<!-- VENTANA MODAL -->
<?php
        foreach ($trabajos as $trabajo) {
        $contador = $contador+1
    ?>
    <div class="modal fade" id="staticBackdrop_<?php echo $contador ?>" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content border border-2 border-primary">
                <div class="modal-header d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <h2 class="modal-title fw-bold" id="staticBackdropLabel"><?php echo $trabajo->titulo;?></h2>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row mb-3">
                <div class="row mb-3">
                    <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                        <p class="lead color-azul pe-2"><b><i class="fa-solid fa-graduation-cap pt-3 pe-1"></i>CARRERA DE:</p>
                        <div class="col">
                            <input class="form-control text-center" type="text" value="<?php echo $trabajo->carrera;?>" aria-label="readonly input example" readonly>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

Estoy trabado hace bastante con esto, agradeceria mucho la ayuda :)

Comment: Esta pregunta se ha respondido miles de veces en este sitio, y es la repetición de ids normalmente la causa. Cómo no has puesto el modal, en este caso podría ser la repeticion de esto: `data-bs-target="#staticBackdrop"` que siempre apunta al mismo id, y si lo tienes repetido entonces solo te coge el primero.  Solución: No repitas ids y no llames al mismo en todos los botones generados en el bucle.

Comment: Agrega como generas el modal para saber exactamente en que caso estás trabado.

Comment: Hola, gracias por las observaciones, ya agregué lo que tengo en el modal pero sinceramente no sé como seguir, gracias

Comment: Debes cambiar esto: `id="staticBackdrop" ` por un id único, por ejemplo: `id="staticBackdrop_<?=contador?>"`, donde $contador sea una variable inicializada **antes** del bucle y dentro del mismo le vas agregando uno con `contador++;`, y haces lo mismo con ambos bucles (en el otro lo debes hacer aquí: `data-bs-target="#staticBackdrop"`)

Comment: O si no quieres meter un contador, puedes aprovecharte de las variables pasadas asi:  `id="staticBackdrop_<?=$trabajo->ID?>"` y así: `data-bs-target="#staticBackdrop_<?=$trabajo->ID?>"` (suponiendo que no se repita ese $trabajo->ID en otro ciclo)

Comment: Hola, realicé cambios en el código pero sigue sin funcionar, agradeceria una última ayuda, gracias de antemano :d

Comment: No veo que inicialices el $contador antes del segundo bucle, y si está todo en el mismo script quizas está continuando la cuenta del primero.  Pon un `$contador = 0;` antes de iniciar el segundo bucle para que así coincida con los valores del primero.

Comment: Funcionó, muchisimas gracias, sos un grandee <3